# CryptoServiceProvider hash output does not match online hash generators?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm a student and I'm new to programming. This is the first C# program I've tried to write. The program is supposed to read in a text file with clear text and then output a text file with MD5 and SHA-1 hashes. The program works so far as I can tell, however the hashes created by my program do not match the hashes generated by online hash generators. To the best of my knowledge hashes should match if the input word is the same. Is there anything obviously wrong with my code that would cause this?

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace CreateHash
{
class Program
{
    const string INPUTFILE = "C:\\ClearTextPasswords.txt";
    const string OUTPUTFILEMD5 = "C:\\EncryptedMD5Passwords.txt";
    const string OUTPUTFILESHA1 = "C:\\EncryptedSHA1Passwords.txt";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input;
        int counter = 0;

        DeleteWriteFile();

        StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(INPUTFILE);

        while ((input = readFile.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if(AppendFile(input))
                counter++;
        }

        readFile.Close();

        Console.WriteLine("\nSuccessfully wrote {0} encrypted password(s) to: \n{1} and\n{2} files.\n\nPress any key to exit...", counter.ToString(), OUTPUTFILEMD5, OUTPUTFILESHA1);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void DeleteWriteFile()
    {
        //Example of try/catch block
        try
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(OUTPUTFILEMD5);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There was an error deleting the MD5 Output file: " + ex.Message);
        }

        try
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(OUTPUTFILESHA1);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There was an error deleting the MD5 Output file: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    static bool AppendFile(string str)
    {
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        bool result = false;

        StreamWriter writeFile1;
        StreamWriter writeFile2;

        HashToolkit hashToolkit = new HashToolkit();

        //Example of try/catch/finally block
        try
        {
            writeFile1 = new StreamWriter(OUTPUTFILEMD5, true);
            writeFile1.WriteLine(hashToolkit.GetMd5(str));
            writeFile1.Close();
            x = 1;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There was an error writing to the MD5 Output file: " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            writeFile1 = null;
        }

        try
        {
            writeFile2 = new StreamWriter(OUTPUTFILESHA1, true);
            writeFile2.WriteLine(hashToolkit.GetSha1(str));
            writeFile2.Close();
            y = 1;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There was an error writing to the SHA1 Output file: " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            writeFile2 = null;
        }

        if (x * y != 0)
            result = true;

        return result;
    }
}

public class HashToolkit
{
    public HashToolkit()
    {
    }

    public string GetMd5(string str)
    {
        MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        string input = string.Empty;

        byte[] hashedData = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(str));

        foreach (byte b in hashedData)
        {
            input += String.Format("{0,2:X2}", b);
        }
        return input;
    }

    public string GetSha1(string str)
    {
        SHA1 sha = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
        string input = string.Empty;

        byte[] hashedData = sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(str));

        foreach (byte b in hashedData)
        {
            input += String.Format("{0,2:X2}", b);
        }
        return input;
    }
}
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: You're converting the file to UTF-16-LE before hashing. Why do you decode is as text in the first place, instead of using the bytes directly? Alternatively you can use `Encoding.UTF8` instead of `Encoding.Unicode`.

Comment: Instead of looping through the bytes, just use [`ToBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

That's because you can't hash strings, you can only hash bytes. For that reason you need to convert to bytes first. And you are using UTF16 for that. The online tool probably uses UTF8 or some ASCII-style encoding. Find out which it uses and use it too.